# R - ggplot2 time series x-axis to show last day of the month

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Why does ggplot keeps giving me the first day of the month then plotting a time series.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
date <- as.Date(c("2008-01-31",
"2008-02-29",
"2008-03-31",
"2008-04-30",
"2008-05-31"))


count <- sample(5)
df <- data.frame(date = date, count = count)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = count))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
               date_labels = '%m/%d')
```

I want the x-axis to show the actual date from the `df` or the last day of the month. But instead it shows the first day of the next month.
I tried searching for this but could not find a applicable solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the most straightforward solution is simply to use `breaks` instead of `date_breaks`, referring directly to your column of dates in the dataframe.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = count))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%m/%d', breaks = df$date)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Removing `date_breaks` and adding `breaks = df$date` seems to give the desired outcome.

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(date), count = count)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = count)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = df$date, date_labels = '%m/%d')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You and `ggplot` are thinking about the dates differently.

You're thinking about the dates like labels. In your example you have 5 things, which you want plotted in order, and those labels should appear on the axis.

`ggplot` is thinking about the dates like dates. If you only gave it the values 2 and 5, as they're numeric it would add all the points between them, e.g. 2.5, 3, 4, etc. Since you've given dates, it sticks all the dates in between as well.

The axis labels go off the range of the axis, and have nothing to do with the variable. It's placed the dates in the right spot, but then chosen the axis labels itself.

This leaves you with two options

1.

If you want to stick with the data type "Date", swap the `date_break` option with just `breaks` and specify the range of what you want. e.g.

```
scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(date),max(date),by="month"),
             date_labels = '%m/%d')
```

2.

If you actually want these to be labels (e.g. you don't want to put any points between these dates), consider making `date` a factor and just plotting that.

```
date <- factor(c("2008-01-31",
              "2008-02-29",
              "2008-03-31",
              "2008-04-30",
              "2008-05-31"))

count <- sample(5)
df <- data.frame(date = date, count = count)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(date), y = count))+
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=format(as.Date(date), "%m/%d"))
```

Wrapping `as.numeric` around date in the `aes` argument converts the Factor to numeric (so it will draw a line between it), we then just need to set the label to what we want it to be, which requires converting it to a date then formatting it to month/day.